# "Google Play Services which are missing from your phone" on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, android-maps-v2, google-play-services

Hey I am trying to use google maps on my emulator even though I've installed google play services library when I run the app it says

"This app won't run without google play services which are missing from your phone"

Comment: According to document on the android developer site, you must use either:
- A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Does your Android emulator satisfy the last condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Services is different from the Google Play Services library. The library grants your application to APIs provided by Google Play Services.

The emulator unfortunately does not support Google Play Services pre-4.2.2.
From the [Setup Google Play Services developers guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html):

> If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>   Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>   install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform
>   target.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator unfortunately does not support google play services per 4.2.2 from the setup google play services developer guide.

Answer (score 0):

Run your emulator and install two files named **com.google.android.gms** and **com.google.vending**. As com.google.android.gms is what that is called Google play services so be sure that the apk you are installing has got the same version as your SDK's Google play services library's version. Installation of these two files is as mentioned in this link [Running Google Mapsv2](http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/)

**(For testing app on real device)**
If you are using Android 2.2 then you must add Google play services for Froyo (library) in your project rather than Google play services library. Open your SDK manager and look under Extras, you will find one. But if you are trying to test your app against Android higher than 2.2, you must go with the answers mentioned above.